# Commas are inserted in infinite decimals

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I am developing an app in VS that uses global coordinates for Google Maps polylines. I am using C#3.5, and working on Windows 8. When run, my program generates a number of coordinates, and outputs them in a js code in a html file.
On my computer, the program works fine, it is doing its job, and generates a js code with coordinates like this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(47.6370775, 19.0505071666666667),
new google.maps.LatLng(47.637077333333333, 19.0505070),
new google.maps.LatLng(47.6370775, 19.0505066666666667),
```

However, when I run the program on the computer I wish to use later, something strange occurs, and it outputs a code like this:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(47.6370775, 19.0505071,666666667),
new google.maps.LatLng(47.637077,333333333, 19.0505070),
new google.maps.LatLng(47.6370775, 19.0505066,666666667),
```

Note the commas before the infinite decimals. Said computer runs a Windows XP SP3, so it is a lot older system, but it has .NET 3.5 installed on it. Using these coordinates produces unexpected results in Google Maps (it placed the center point in Syria, rather than Hungary, where it is meant to be).
I am not sure if the OS, or my app makes the changes, and I cannot debug, because this system does not have VS installed (and I am not able install it).

**Update:**

The raw coordinate taken from a text file:

```
01903.43995
```

The conversion method (latitude is the coordinate above in string)

```
latitude = latitude.TrimStart('0');
latitude = latitude.Insert(2, ".");
string[] currentcoord = latitude.Split('.');
string temp = currentcoord[1] + currentcoord[2];
string[] temp2;
if ((((double.Parse(temp) / 60) * 100).ToString()).Contains("."))
{
   temp2 = (((double.Parse(temp) / 60) * 100).ToString()).Split('.');
   currentcoord[1] = temp2[0] + temp2[1];
}
else
{
   currentcoord[1] = ((double.Parse(temp) / 60) * 100).ToString();
}
converted += currentcoord[0] + "." + currentcoord[1] + ";";
```

"converted" is the result of the conversion, the coordinate which is then used as the output.
(In this case, it should be 19.0505071666666667, or something similar).

Comment: What is generating the numbers?

Comment: Clearly "your program" does not "work fine", but without seeing actual code that produces the numbers it is not possible to suggest anything concrete. Most likely you handling culture-specific conversion of numbers wrong... but hard to say for sure.

Comment: I have updated the question with the conversion method.
Please also note, that the coordinates generated under my computer are the ones I am looking for. They are very accurate, and there is no problem with them or whatsoever. So I do not wish to have different numbers, but these numbers without the commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other computer might have different regional settings and so `.ToString()` produces a value without `'.'` which you rely upon.

You should use `.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and `Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead.

Comment: What he said.  You can also put the line `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` before the conversion code.

Comment: You're welcome! I would recommend you to simplify your code, at least get rid of the obvious repetitions.

Comment: Yes, the whole code is a bit inconsistent, as this was a side-project only, and I made it in a hurry. Perhaps I will polish it in the future :) But it consumes a minimum amount of resources, so it does not suffers from performance problems. But thank you for the advice!